# Analytics for Firebase - Debugging events and user properties

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm working with firebase analytics for my android App, I know firebase works as a Data layer and then this info is sent to Analytics for Firebase.

I need to test all my events and user properties before moving to production, but i dont want to send data to firebase beacuase it wont be true data.

**Is there any way to prevent this so i can debug without sending untrue data?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can turn on debug mode and see the events and user properties in real-time on debug view (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview). In that way, you can verify that your instrument is good to go.